# Validation Error: Element hr not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: html, validation

I am encountering the following error on the [HTML Validator site](http://validator.w3.org).

This is the error message i am getting :

```
Element hr not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
```

This is my html code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li><hr>
        <li><a href="displayallbooks.php">Display All Books</a></li><hr>
        <li><a href="searchbooksform.php">Search Books</a></li><hr>
        <li><a href="credits.php">Credits</a></li><hr>

    </ul>   
</nav>
```

Any helps would be appreciated. Thank you .

Comment: What do you want to achive with this source code?

Comment: I am creating menu buttons on my website

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Its already stated there @JukkaK.Korpela . I need to validate the html file using the link above. I should get zero errors in the validator. but now i am getting this error message as shown above

Comment: No, you did not ask any question. And you get zero error messages by removing the errors.

Comment: Well to tell exactly my question was i need to use the <hr> tag. Actually i dont understand about the validation message above. Can i know what is that mean?

Comment: I think the error message is clear. You closed the list element so, the following hr tag is an child element of `ul`. The validator did complain about this fact.

Comment: @reporter how can i solve this problem?

Comment: S@RaajLokanathan Look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on HTML validator, my comment underneath the question and my tries on Jsfiddle, change your code into this way:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a><hr/></li>
        <li><a href="displayallbooks.php">Display All Books</a><hr/></li>
        <li><a href="searchbooksform.php">Search Books</a><hr/></li>
        <li><a href="credits.php">Credits</a><hr/></li>
    </ul> 
</nav>
```

The source code I used at HTML validort's site was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>t</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a><hr/></li>
        <li><a href="displayallbooks.php">Display All Books</a><hr/></li>
        <li><a href="searchbooksform.php">Search Books</a><hr/></li>
        <li><a href="credits.php">Credits</a><hr/></li>
    </ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

It gave me zero erros. With your tag `nav`, the validor complained about this tag.

Comment: it works but my border-bottom length is too short how can i make it fit to a block

Comment: @RaajLokanathan you can add the arrtribut style with its value `width:<your size in pixels or percentage>`. Note: The possibilities for styling this element are limited.

Answer (score 0):

I listed the hr elements as li tags in the ul. I formatted the hr tag in CSS (set the width in px).

```
<ul class="navlinks">
        <li>
          <div class="logo-mobile"><img class="logo-m" src="./logo-bookmark-white.svg.svg" alt="bookmark-logo"></div>
        </li>
        <li><hr></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="navlink">Features</a></li>
        <li><hr></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="navlink">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><hr></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="navlink">Contact</a></li>
        <li><hr></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="login-btn navlinnk">Login</button></li> 
      </ul>
```

```
hr {
    display: block;
    opacity: 70%;
    width: 300px;
}
```